# memory efficient way to write an uncompressed file from a gzip file

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip, generator, shutil

using Python 3.5

I am uncompressing a gzip file, writing to another file.  After looking into an out of memory problem, I find an example in the docs for the gzip module:

```
import gzip
import shutil
with open('/home/joe/file.txt', 'rb') as f_in:
    with gzip.open('/home/joe/file.txt.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

This does compression, and I want uncompression, so I take it that I can just reverse the pattern, giving

```
with open(unzipped_file, 'wb') as f_out, gzip.open(zipped_file, 'rb') as f_in:
    shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

My question is, why did I get into memory trouble with the following:

```
with gzip.open(zipped_file, 'rb') as zin, open(unzipped_file, 'wb') as wout:
    wout.write(zin.read())
```

Either I laid on the last straw, or I was naive in believing that the files would act like generators and stream the unzip process, taking very little memory.  Should these two methods be equivalent?

Comment: I suggest you look at the code of the `shutil.copyfileObj` method.

Comment: "*I was naive in believing that the files would act like generators*" -- That's it. You answered your own question. For proof, try `print(type(zin.read())` for some smaller file.

Comment: The `copyfileobj`  uses file objects and internally performs similar read and write operations as  `file.read(blocksize)`  and  `file.write(chunk)` . In that sense, using  `copyfileobj`  may not provide a significant advantage over directly using the  `read` and  `write`  methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the `shutil.copyfileObj` method.

```
def copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst, length=16*1024):
    """copy data from file-like object fsrc to file-like object fdst"""
    while 1:
        buf = fsrc.read(length)
        if not buf:
            break
        fdst.write(buf)
```

It reads the file in chunks of length of 16*1024. And when you are trying to reverse the process, you are not taking regard of the size of the file which will get read into memory and land you into memory problem.

Comment: I see this is the cleaner solution, rather than for me to essentially duplicate it as I've shown.

Comment: I don't like to use `break`-statements for readability. Mostly I read one chunk prior to the `while`-statement and then read the chunks again at the end of the `while`-loop, so you can use `while chunk:` without a `break`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the memory hungry (and naive)

```
import gzip
with gzip.open(zipped_file, 'rb') as zin, open(unzipped_file, 'wb') as wout:
     wout.write(zin.read())
```

Based on the earlier answers I tested this:

```
import gzip
block_size = 64*1024
with gzip.open(zipped_file, 'rb') as zin, open(unzipped_file, 'wb') as wout:
while True:
    uncompressed_block = zin.read(block_size)
    if not uncompressed_block:
        break
    wout.write(uncompressed_block)
```

Verified on a 4.8G file.

Comment: I feel like this must have been asked and answered elsewhere.  Anyone have a link?

Comment: The solution by @Vinit and mentioned by Jean-Francois is best.